# Can a braced initializer be used for non-type template argument in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, list-initialization

In the next program the second non-type template argument of `struct A` is initialized with `{}` in the alias template `B<T>`:

```
template<class T, T>
struct A{};

template<class T>
using B = A<T, {}>;

B<int> b;
```

GCC is the only compiler accepting this. Both Clang and MSVC reject the program with similar errors. Clang:

```
error: expected expression
```

MSVC:

```
error C2760: syntax error: '{' was unexpected here; expected 'expression'
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6bc3sx451

Which compiler is right here?

Comment: The intent is to allow it http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2450 (also mentioned in the comments on the target). This hasn't landed yet afaik, so I think GCC is just being permissive here.

Comment: This appears to be a weird use of a GCC extension known as [statement expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html). (I was thinking of posting an answer but then it was closed...)

Comment: @AdrianMole I don't think that's right. GCC just explicitly allows using braced-init-list as a template parameter, even though the language doesn't allow it yet.

Comment: @cigien Yeah, I think you're right. Otherwise, what would the value/type of the 'expression' actually be?

Comment: @AdrianMole The statement expressions syntax requires parentheses around the brace-enclosed block as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say GCC is wrong.

The grammar for *template-argument* in [[temp.names]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.names#nt:template-argument) says that a template argument must either be a *constant-expression*, a *type-id* or an *id-expression*.

`{}` is neither an expression, nor a type, nor an (un)qualified name.